# How to call C inline assembly asm in cython?

Tags: c, cython, inline-assembly

How to call C language's inline assembly function `asm()` in cython? I tried a simple `asm("mov $eax, 0x1") or __asm__()`. It cythonizes fine until the `asm`-call, which then give me below error:

> NameError: name 'asm' is not defined

I compile my code as `python setup.py build_ext --inplace && python runids.py`

Comment: Separate from getting `asm()` to work, your choice of example is pretty insane. AT&T syntax `mov $eax, 0x1` has an immediate source operand, the address of the symbol `eax`, e.g. C global scope `int eax;`, *not* the register `%eax`.  And the destination operand is memory at absolute address `1`.  So... I'm guessing that wasn't what you wanted to write.  Fortunately you didn't modify any registers, so it would be a "safe" instruction to run in GNU C inline asm as a Basic Asm statement (no clobber declarations on regs or `"memory"`), since that address won't be the address of any C variable.

Comment: The other point I should have made is that GNU C Basic Asm is not safe or truly usable for anything except for the body of `__attribute__((naked))` functions, or at global scope (as an alternative to a separate `.s` file).  Or maybe for `asm("mfence");` or something with no registers if using a GCC version that has an implicit `"memory"` clobber on Basic Asm statements.  You need to be looking for Cython support for Extended Asm, which in C looks like `asm ("inc %0" : "+r"(var));`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: `asm` is not a function. It just happens to look like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to call assembler directly from Cython. The best you can do is to wrap `asm` in a C-function and call it from Cython - for example using [verbatim C-code](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#including-verbatim-c-code) like this (here for gcc):

```
%%cython

cdef extern from *:
    """
    void inline_asm_fun(void){
        __asm__("mov $1, %%eax" ::: "eax");
    }
    """
    void inline_asm_fun()
    
def use_inline_asm():
    inline_asm_fun()
```

As @PeterCordes has pointed out, to do something useful in inline-assembler one should use [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended), i.e. `__asm__("mov $1, %%eax" ::: "eax")` instead of simple and unsafe `__asm__("mov $1, %eax")`. The latter would modify `%eax` without notifying the compiler about it.

For MVSC, the nonstandard extension for inline-assembler is [`__asm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/inline-assembler?view=msvc-160) but it is only supported for x86 and not x64.

Comment: You need to make your C function `__attribute__((naked))` (and manually use `ret`) if you're going to modify EAX without telling the compiler about it.  Or better, use a clobber `__asm__("mov $1, %%eax" ::: "eax");` or use an `"=r"(var)` output operand.  Please don't write unsafe inline asm, even as an example of something else; it's hard enough to learn without misleading examples.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just took OP's example. I hope taking "nop" doesn't break anything...

Comment: Yes, `nop` is safe.  There's no guarantee where it will end up in the compiler-generated asm after inlining, but it's a NOP, not `cli` or `mfence` or something, so that doesn't matter either.  (And newish GCC does have an implicit `"memory"` clobber on non-empty Basic Asm statements.)  Still, I might have done `__asm__("mov $1, %%eax" ::: "eax")` just to make the point that you need Extended Asm to do anything useful with asm inside a C function.

Comment: Most readers are going to assume they can replace "nop" with whatever other instruction, but here it's *not* a placeholder, it's the only safe thing with that Basic asm syntax.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234033/discussion-between-ead-and-hashy).